# How do I get my emoticons in my text?

Tags: c#, emoticons

I have made a chat app in C# in visual studio 2015. I have some emoticons in the app but I also want them to get into the text. There is only one problem. They erase the whole text. How can I make it so that the emoticons come with the text and not erase it all?
(sorry for my bad english because i'm Dutch)

Thanks...

Comment: It is difficult to help you with only the description of the problem you provided.   Somewhere along the way in my own career I read "How to Ask Questions the Smart Way" by Eric S. Raymond.    It helped me immensely, perhaps it might help you.   Here is a link in case you are interested: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html      Also,  posting some code that demonstrates your problem could help us understand your situation and your question.

Comment: Provide us with some sample code to see what you are doing wrong and we can help you to make it right. Your English is understandable.

Comment: If you cannot provide sample code, at least a screen shot of your application so we have an idea when we are dealing with.

Comment: As they have said, add sample code.  But without code, it sounds like you are replacing the text with an emoticon instead of appending it. :)

Comment: You could pass text in a hidden field before it is erased by the emoticon. It depends on what is your situation